# send a alert when value of a column reaches a certain value

Tags: database, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g and I have a table where values are inserted in ascending order (but does not use a DB sequence).

I want to get a email notification when the value reaches a certain number or above, what is the easiest way to do this?  does oracle offer anything like this or will it be easiest to write a job externally to connect to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger on the table(s) where the value gets stored, and when the value of interest is inserted, use DBMS_JOB to send the email.

Since jobs created with DBMS_JOB don't run until a commit is encountered, the email will only get sent when the value is successfully committed to the database.